# Make html5 video player not switching to full screen in IOS

Tags: html, ios, fullscreen

I have to make a html5 video player to full screen. I have used the full screen API methods. But this is not working in chrome or in safari in IOS devices, working in android and windows browsers. I there any better option to make it work in IOS browsers.

Answer (score 0):

For displaying a video Properly for all browsers with **HTML**, you can use this code:

```html
<video controls>
<source src="your-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<p>If you are seeing this your browser is not supported for the video</p>
<video>
```

It works for almost **all browsers** now, including IOS browsers.
This code **may not work for very old browsers** like Internet Explorer.